# Corona SDK - Can you change the device's volume setting or at least get the device's volume setting

Tags: audio, audio-recording, coronasdk

Corona SDK has apis like audio.setVolume and audio.setMaxVolume and audio.getVolume

But it seems as though these do nothing more than change the maximum volume in the Corona environment or get the volume in the corona environment.

My app lets you record your voice and play it back.  When users can't hear themselves, they complain and blame my app.

I've found that in most cases ( possibly all, but I can't verify ), users tell me the volume was somehow set to off but they didn't realize it.   And for some reason they don't check the volume first before wondering why they hear no sound.

If I could show the user what the device's volume is, this would solve the problem.  And if I could give them a slider to update the volume for the device, even better for users who are confused by how to change volume through the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible to get the device volume at this time using Corona.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for iOS but not Android... check out the following link: http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/06/05/new-audiosession-properties

```
if audio.supportsSessionProperty then
    local master_ringer_volume = audio.getSessionProperty(1667788662)
    if (master_ringer_volume ~= nil) then
        if (master_ringer_volume < 0.25) then
            -- Do whatever you need to here...
        end
    end
end
```